Error when merging table cells in google doc using app script
I am trying to merge the top row of a table in a Google Doc using app script.  I was getting an error so tried the merge code alone on a simple table. The same thing happens.
Here is the code, which is a sample from the documentation. It seems to work but when I switch back to the document, I get an error and have to reload.  I've tried Chrome and Firefox.  Any ideas?

    function testMerge(){
      var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
      var documentTab = doc.getActiveTab().asDocumentTab();
      var body = documentTab.getBody();

      // Example 2: Merge table cells
      // Create a two-dimensional array containing the table's cell contents.
      var cells = [
          ['Row 1, Cell 1', 'Row 1, Cell 2'],
          ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2']
      ];
      // Build a table from the array.
      var table = body.appendTable(cells);
      // Get the first row in the table.
      var row = table.getRow(0);
      // Get the two cells in this row.
      var cell1 = row.getCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.getCell(1);
      // Merge the current cell into its preceding sibling element.
      var merged = cell2.merge();
    }

The first row does actually merge, but I have to reload the file.  I can continue coding for now but if I can't get past this, the final product won't be usable.

I guessed that your issue might be related to this issue tracker. Ref It seems like a bug. About merge the top row of a table in a Google Doc using app script, in this case, how about using Google Docs API as follows?
When your showing script is modified, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services.
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var documentTab = doc.getActiveTab().asDocumentTab();
  var body = documentTab.getBody();

  // Example 2: Merge table cells
  // Create a two-dimensional array containing the table's cell contents.
  var cells = [
    ['Row 1, Cell 1', 'Row 1, Cell 2'],
    ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2']
  ];
  // Build a table from the array.
  body.appendTable(cells);


  // --- I modified the below script.
  doc.saveAndClose();
  const id = doc.getId();
  const index = Docs.Documents.get(id).body.content.findLast(({ table }) => table).startIndex;
  const requests = [
    {
      mergeTableCells: {
        tableRange: {
          columnSpan: 2,
          rowSpan: 1,
          tableCellLocation: { tableStartLocation: { index }, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0 }
        }

      }
    }
  ];
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, id);
}

Testing:
When this script is run to the empty document, the following result is obtained without your error message.

References:

Method: documents.batchUpdate
MergeTableCellsRequest

